# SSL Connection on Android devices with Jetty Client not possible

Tags: android, jetty, comet

I am trying to use **Cometd 2.9.1** library on Android for HTTP streaming updates. It uses **Jetty 7.6.17** for creating a *long-polling HttpClient*.

This setup worked great so far on many different Android devices from **OS 4.0.1** upwards.

The service URL is available under HTTPS too and we need to switch using it via HTTPS. This is causing serious problems.

I am not able to connect to the server with HTTPS via Jetty HttpClient on many of our test devices:

- Sony Z1 Compact - Android 5.0.2
- Nexus 7 - Android 4.4.4
- Nexus S - Android 4.1.2

It however works on

- Nexus 4 - Android 5.1.1

I get the following error:

```
07-09 15:14:38.886  24635-24663/com.troii.bayeuxclient E/ROOT﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:38.887 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerFactory.getLogger(AndroidLoggerFactory.java:41)
    Logger configuration file is empty. Default configuration will be used
07-09 15:14:38.896      487-501/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.troii.bayeuxclient/.MainActivity: +2s228ms
07-09 15:14:38.896  24635-24663/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.util.log﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:38.899 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    Logging to org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter(null) via org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
07-09 15:14:38.906  24635-24663/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:38.913 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    starting org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient@41f7af78
07-09 15:14:38.926  24635-24663/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:38.926 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    starting SslContextFactory@41f792d0(null,null)
07-09 15:14:38.926  24635-24663/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:38.930 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    No keystore or trust store configured.  ACCEPTING UNTRUSTED CERTIFICATES!!!!!
07-09 15:14:39.206  24635-24663/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.214 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    STARTED SslContextFactory@41f792d0(null,null)
07-09 15:14:39.216  24635-24663/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.219 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    starting null/null
07-09 15:14:39.226  24635-24663/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.230 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    STARTED PooledBuffers [0/1024@6144,0/1024@16384,0/1024@-]/PooledBuffers [0/1024@6144,0/1024@32768,0/1024@-]
07-09 15:14:39.226  24635-24663/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.235 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    starting HttpClient{8<=0<=0/16,-1}
07-09 15:14:39.246  24635-24663/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.252 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    STARTED HttpClient{8<=8<=8/16,0}
07-09 15:14:39.256  24635-24663/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.256 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    starting org.eclipse.jetty.client.SelectConnector@41f91708
07-09 15:14:39.256  24635-24663/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.261 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    starting org.eclipse.jetty.client.SelectConnector$Manager@41f7faa0
07-09 15:14:39.276  24635-24663/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.274 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    STARTED org.eclipse.jetty.client.SelectConnector$Manager@41f7faa0
07-09 15:14:39.276  24635-24671/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio﹕ 2015-0007-0009 0015:0014:0039.274 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    Starting Thread[HttpClient-2220 Selector0,5,main] on org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$1@42005a40
07-09 15:14:39.286  24635-24663/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.287 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    STARTED org.eclipse.jetty.client.SelectConnector@41f91708
07-09 15:14:39.296  24635-24663/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.296 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    STARTED org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient@41f7af78
07-09 15:14:39.336  24635-24663/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpExchange﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.341 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    URI = https://cometd.server.com/http_push/
07-09 15:14:39.356  24635-24663/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpExchange﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.359 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    setStatus 1 ContentExchange@420125e8=GET//cometd.server.com:443/http_push/#START(17ms)->CONNECTING(1ms)
07-09 15:14:39.406  24635-24663/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 377K, 5% free 8060K/8472K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
07-09 15:14:39.416  24635-24671/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.client.SelectConnector﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.419 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    Channels with connection pending: 0
07-09 15:14:39.426  24635-24671/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.client.SelectConnector﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.431 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    secure to java.nio.SocketChannelImpl@42023320, proxied=false
07-09 15:14:39.546  24635-24671/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.client.SelectConnector﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.551 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    upgrade Upgradable:SSL NEED_WRAP i/o/u=-1/-1/-1 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}} to SslConnection@41f7f858 SSL NEED_WRAP i/o/u=-1/-1/-1 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}} for AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}
07-09 15:14:39.556  24635-24671/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.client.AbstractHttpConnection﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.562 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    Send ContentExchange@420125e8=GET//cometd.server.com:443/http_push/#START(17ms)->CONNECTING(202ms) on AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}
07-09 15:14:39.566  24635-24671/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpExchange﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.571 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    setStatus 2 ContentExchange@420125e8=GET//cometd.server.com:443/http_push/#CONNECTING(215ms)->CONNECTED(0ms)
07-09 15:14:39.606  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.612 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 SslConnection@41f7f858 SSL NEED_WRAP i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}} NEED_WRAP filled=0/0 flushed=0/0
07-09 15:14:39.616  24635-24671/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio﹕ 2015-007-09 15:14:39.612 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    created SCEP@41ffa990{l(cometd.server.com/91.220.8.20:443)<->r(/192.168.0.13:54813),s=1,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=0}-{SslConnection@41f7f858 SSL NEED_WRAP i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}}}
07-09 15:14:39.626  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.626 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 wrap OK NEED_UNWRAP consumed=0 produced=78
07-09 15:14:39.636  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.645 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 SslConnection@41f7f858 SSL NEED_UNWRAP i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}} NEED_UNWRAP filled=0/0 flushed=78/0
07-09 15:14:39.656  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.662 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 SslConnection@41f7f858 SSL NEED_UNWRAP i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}} NEED_UNWRAP filled=0/0 flushed=0/0
07-09 15:14:39.666  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.client.AsyncHttpConnection﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.670 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    while open=true more=false progress=true
07-09 15:14:39.686  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.client.AsyncHttpConnection﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.685 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    exchange ContentExchange@420125e8=GET//cometd.server.com:443/http_push/#CONNECTING(215ms)->CONNECTED(107ms) on AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}
07-09 15:14:39.696  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.client.AsyncHttpConnection﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.695 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    commit ContentExchange@420125e8=GET//cometd.server.com:443/http_push/#CONNECTING(215ms)->CONNECTED(122ms)
07-09 15:14:39.706  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpExchange﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.706 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    setStatus 3 ContentExchange@420125e8=GET//cometd.server.com:443/http_push/#CONNECTED(132ms)->SENDING(1ms)sent=1ms
07-09 15:14:39.736  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 320K, 5% free 8252K/8608K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
07-09 15:14:39.776  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpExchange﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.785 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    setStatus 4 ContentExchange@420125e8=GET//cometd.server.com:443/http_push/#SENDING(80ms)->WAITING(0ms)sent=80ms
07-09 15:14:39.796  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.798 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 SslConnection@41f7f858 SSL NEED_UNWRAP i/o/u=3514/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=2,h=58,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}} NEED_UNWRAP filled=3514/3514 flushed=0/0
07-09 15:14:39.806  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.808 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 unwrap OK NEED_UNWRAP consumed=79 produced=0
07-09 15:14:39.816  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.820 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 SslConnection@41f7f858 SSL NEED_UNWRAP i/o/u=3435/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=2,h=58,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}} NEED_UNWRAP filled=0/3435 flushed=0/0
07-09 15:14:39.856  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.862 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 unwrap OK NEED_UNWRAP consumed=3426 produced=0
07-09 15:14:39.866  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.874 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 SslConnection@41f7f858 SSL NEED_UNWRAP i/o/u=9/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=2,h=58,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}} NEED_UNWRAP filled=0/9 flushed=0/0
07-09 15:14:39.876  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.880 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 unwrap OK NEED_TASK consumed=9 produced=0
07-09 15:14:39.886  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.892 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 SslConnection@41f7f858 SSL NEED_TASK i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=2,h=58,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}} NEED_TASK filled=0/0 flushed=0/0
07-09 15:14:39.906  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.912 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 SslConnection@41f7f858 SSL NEED_WRAP i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=2,h=58,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}} NEED_WRAP filled=0/0 flushed=0/0
07-09 15:14:39.916  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.918 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 wrap OK NEED_WRAP consumed=0 produced=267
07-09 15:14:39.926  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.930 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 SslConnection@41f7f858 SSL NEED_WRAP i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=2,h=58,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}} NEED_WRAP filled=0/0 flushed=267/0
07-09 15:14:39.936  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.943 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 wrap OK NEED_WRAP consumed=0 produced=6
07-09 15:14:39.946  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.955 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 SslConnection@41f7f858 SSL NEED_WRAP i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=2,h=58,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}} NEED_WRAP filled=0/0 flushed=6/0
07-09 15:14:39.956  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.961 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 wrap OK NEED_UNWRAP consumed=0 produced=41
07-09 15:14:39.966  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.974 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 SslConnection@41f7f858 SSL NEED_UNWRAP i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=2,h=58,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}} NEED_UNWRAP filled=0/0 flushed=41/0
07-09 15:14:39.986  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.987 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 SslConnection@41f7f858 SSL NEED_UNWRAP i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=2,h=58,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}} NEED_UNWRAP filled=0/0 flushed=0/0
07-09 15:14:39.986  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.client.AsyncHttpConnection﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:39.993 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    complete ContentExchange@420125e8=GET//cometd.server.com:443/http_push/#SENDING(80ms)->WAITING(211ms)sent=291ms
07-09 15:14:39.996  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:40.005 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 SslConnection@41f7f858 SSL NEED_UNWRAP i/o/u=47/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=3,h=58,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}} NEED_UNWRAP filled=47/47 flushed=0/0
07-09 15:14:40.006  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:40.011 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 unwrap OK NEED_UNWRAP consumed=6 produced=0
07-09 15:14:40.026  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:40.032 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 SslConnection@41f7f858 SSL NEED_UNWRAP i/o/u=41/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=3,h=58,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}} NEED_UNWRAP filled=0/41 flushed=0/0
07-09 15:14:40.136  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:40.139 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 unwrap OK NOT_HANDSHAKING consumed=228 produced=203
07-09 15:14:40.146  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:40.155 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    ishut SCEP@41ffa990{l(cometd.server.com/91.220.8.20:443)<->r(/192.168.0.13:54813),s=1,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=0}-{SslConnection@41f7f858 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=57/0/203 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=3,h=0,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}}}
07-09 15:14:40.166  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:40.166 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 SslConnection@41f7f858 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=57/0/203 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=3,h=0,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=-1/57 flushed=0/0
07-09 15:14:40.166  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:40.172 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 unwrap OK NOT_HANDSHAKING consumed=30 produced=5
07-09 15:14:40.176  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:40.184 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 SslConnection@41f7f858 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=27/0/208 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=3,h=0,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=-1/27 flushed=0/0
07-09 15:14:40.186  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:40.190 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 unwrap CLOSED NEED_WRAP consumed=27 produced=0
07-09 15:14:40.196  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:40.201 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    unwrap CLOSE SslConnection@41f7f858 SSL NEED_WRAP i/o/u=0/0/208 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=3,h=0,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}} SSLEngineReport: Status = CLOSED  HandshakeStatus = NEED_WRAP
    bytesConsumed = 27 bytesProduced = 0
07-09 15:14:40.206  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:40.215 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    oshut SCEP@41ffa990{l(cometd.server.com/91.220.8.20:443)<->r(/192.168.0.13:54813),s=1,open=true,ishut=true,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=0}-{SslConnection@41f7f858 SSL NEED_WRAP i/o/u=0/0/208 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=3,h=0,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}}}
07-09 15:14:40.226  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:40.230 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    close SCEP@41ffa990{l(cometd.server.com/91.220.8.20:443)<->r(/192.168.0.13:54813),s=1,open=true,ishut=true,oshut=true,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=0}-{SslConnection@41f7f858 SSL NEED_WRAP i/o/u=0/0/208 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=3,h=0,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}}}
07-09 15:14:40.256  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:40.260 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 SslConnection@41f7f858 SSL NEED_WRAP i/o/u=0/0/208 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=3,h=0,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}} NEED_WRAP filled=-1/0 flushed=0/0
07-09 15:14:40.266  24635-24671/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:40.267 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    destroyEndPoint SCEP@41ffa990{l(null)<->r(/192.168.0.13:54813),s=1,open=false,ishut=true,oshut=true,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=0!}-{SslConnection@41f7f858 SSL NEED_WRAP i/o/u=0/0/208 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=3,h=0,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}}}
07-09 15:14:40.266  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:40.275 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 wrap CLOSED NOT_HANDSHAKING consumed=0 produced=27
07-09 15:14:40.286  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:40.286 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    wrap CLOSE SslConnection@41f7f858 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/27/208 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=3,h=0,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}} SSLEngineReport: Status = CLOSED  HandshakeStatus = NOT_HANDSHAKING
    bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 27
07-09 15:14:40.296  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:40.301 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    close SCEP@41ffa990{l(null)<->r(/192.168.0.13:54813),s=1,open=false,ishut=true,oshut=true,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=0-}-{SslConnection@41f7f858 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/27/208 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=3,h=0,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}}}
07-09 15:14:40.306  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:40.314 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl@41f80270 SslConnection@41f7f858 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/27/208 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@41f9d898 cometd.server.com:443 g=HttpGenerator{s=3,h=0,b=-1,c=-1} p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=-1/0 flushed=0/27
07-09 15:14:40.326  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.client.AsyncHttpConnection﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:40.332 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:71)
    Failure on ContentExchange@420125e8=GET//cometd.server.com:443/http_push/#SENDING(80ms)->WAITING(539ms)sent=619ms
    org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
            at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer(HttpGenerator.java:914)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.complete(HttpGenerator.java:798)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.client.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:108)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.handle(SslConnection.java:196)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
            at java.nio.SocketChannelImpl.checkOpenConnected(SocketChannelImpl.java:409)
            at java.nio.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:345)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:293)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.flush(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:401)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.process(SslConnection.java:337)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.access$900(SslConnection.java:48)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection$SslEndPoint.flush(SslConnection.java:690)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.client.SelectConnector$UpgradableEndPoint.flush(SelectConnector.java:341)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer(HttpGenerator.java:844)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.complete(HttpGenerator.java:798)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.client.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:108)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.handle(SslConnection.java:196)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-09 15:14:40.336  24635-24673/com.troii.bayeuxclient D/org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpExchange﹕ 2015-07-09 15:14:40.339 org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter.log(AndroidLoggerAdapter.java:67)
    setStatus 9 ContentExchange@420125e8=GET//cometd.server.com:443/http_push/#WAITING(556ms)->EXCEPTED(0ms)sent=636ms
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be on the server.

At `15:14:40.136` the TLS handshake is complete, and 203 bytes of data were decrypted.

In the next log line you can see `ishut SCEP@41ffa990...` which means that the client read a `-1` from the socket because the server closed the connection.

You have to look at the server logs and understand why the server is closing the connection.

Since this is troubleshooting and not just a question, you may want to join the [CometD mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/cometd-users/).